# calling an async function in the constructor.

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, identityserver4

getUser is an async function? if it is going to take longer time to resolve? is it going to always return the right value in my `someotherclass`.

```
class IdpServer {
    constructor() {
        this._settings = {
            // some identity server settings.
        };
        this.userManager = new UserManager(this._settings);
        this.getUser();
    }

    async getUser() {
        this.user = await this.userManager.getUser();
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
    }
}

let idpServer = new IdpServer();
export default idpServer;


// another class 
// import IdpServer from '...'
 class SomeOtherClass {
     constructor() {
        console.log(IdpServer.isLoggedIn());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Constructors should generally be used to get an object into a usable, valid state.  Not to do lots of work.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Adding on that, a constructor builds an object, it doesn't promise to build part of an object

Comment: I think you're going to have to make the client code `await` the call to `getUser()` before checking the status.

Comment: What does `getUser` do actually?

Comment: it get user object from local storage, and at this point of time, getUser is only being called in constructor.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Alexandre Any better approaches to make sure, it always returns right result?

Comment: Duplicates : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028882/chaining-async-method-calls-javascript,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351146/asynchronous-data-loading-in-class-constructor/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise

Comment: @hashbytes localStorage (if that's what you mean) is synchronous.

Comment: [Just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a problem that is related to [this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Once a code is asynchronous, it cannot be used in synchronous manner. If the use of raw promises is unwanted, all control flow should be performed with `async` functions.

The problem here is that `getUser` provides a promise of user data, not user data itself. A promise is lost in constructor, and this is antipattern.

One way to solve the problem is to provide initialization promise for `IdpServer`, while the rest of API will be synchronous:

```
class IdpServer {
    constructor() {
        ...
        this.initializationPromise = this.getUser(); 
    }

    async getUser() {
        this.user = await this.userManager.getUser();
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
    }
}

// inside async function
await idpServer.initializationPromise;
idpServer.isLoggedIn();
```

Depending on how the application works, `IdpServer.initializationPromise` can be handled on application initialization to guarantee that all units that depend on `IdpServer` won't be initialized until it's ready.

Another way is to make `IdpServer` entirely asynchronous:

```
class IdpServer {
    constructor() {
        ...
        this.user = this.getUser(); // a promise of user data
    }

    async getUser() {
        return this.userManager.getUser();
    }

    async isLoggedIn() {
        const user = await this.user;
        return user != null && !user.expired;
    }
}

// inside async function
await idpServer.isLoggedIn();
```

It's expected that all units that depend on it will also have asynchronous API.

Comment: This is new implementation, 

@estus
this is being int a function, which was being used in 20 places at least in the application. Just thinking if there is an easier way so that it require minimal changes.

Comment: Since this was design mistake, this should be refactored. If a promise exists, there should be a way to chain it in places that depend on the results of this promise. I guess the first way requires less changes and is generally more common.

Comment: Just want to let you guys know, I fixed it by making this as the first thing to run and only when this resolves, then router will render the page template.

Comment: @hashbytes - how can you test for when the promise resolves?